# How can I adjust bars on X-axis accord to numerical order？

Tags: ggplot2

The ideal order of bars on X-axis is (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10).But it just can not be adjust successfully :(
[image]

[image]

```
ggplot(data=T1, aes(x=Scenarios, y=Yields, fill=Scenarios)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)
```

Comment: Please don't use images of your data. Instead paste it in using the output of `dput(T1)`. This will allow people to more easily reproduce your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood ggplot converts the strings to factors and the default levels will be the strings sorted alphabetically (or depending how you create T1, it could be at that point).  If you want to customize the sort order, explicitly cast your x variable as a factor with the level order you prefer.

Either ahead of time:

```
T1 <- dplyr::mutate(T1, Scenarios = factor(Scenarios, Scenarios))
```

or inline with the ggplot call

```
ggplot(aes(x= factor(scenarios, scenarios), y= yields, fill=scenarios)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```